# Hide commands, show text only

Tags: macros, texstudio, editors

Is there a way in TeXstudio, or any other editor, to hide all tags and commands and just show the text?

I would need to translate a .tex file, text is already translated, now I have to bring it back to the .tex file and replace the original text with the translated.

Comment: And the editor should reapply macros to the translated stuff?![Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: I just want to hide everything that would not be seen in the pdf to easily copy the translated text over.

Comment: What should be done with any text contained *inside* the arguments of commands such as `\section`, `\subsection`, `\textbf`, and `\emph`? Should this text be hidden as well, should it be shown as plain text, or something else? Also, does your text contain any math material -- in particular, any inline math? If so, what should be done with `$\alpha$`, `$\beta$`, etc?

Comment: Hi, `\section`, `\subsection` and so on in plain text would be great. No inline math, a few pictures but these can be ignored. Basically I would need the file in plain text with all tags, macros and so on hidden.

Comment: I think you are looking for "lyx" editor and not for TeX studio or a real "plain text editor"... Otherwise just compile and look at the output.

Comment: I think Lyx might work, thank you very much!

Comment: Welcome... Just keep in mind that any advanced ability that TeX gives need some commands too even if you are using Lyx... Good luck.

Comment: I know, thank you, but right now I am not creating a document, it was already created by someone else and I am just translating the text inside, therefore I needed an easy solution to just copy my translated text over.

Comment: Conceptually this is the same as translating an HTML document, which can be done. If I were you, I would just try to find out how it is done there.

Comment: You are right, but html can be parsed by CAT tools like SDL Trados or Memoq, but they cannot really parse .tex, there are ways to open them, but the output is not really what you expect...

Comment: I tried once the `dvi2tty` utility, that can render a DVI file on a teletype terminal: basically, it tries to convert a DVI file (produced by running `latex`—**not** `pdflatex`—on a LaTeX source file) into pure text, and is not as bad at doing so as one might expect! (:-)  Also have a look at [How do I convert LaTeX to plain-text (ASCII)?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/530121) and to [this link](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-toascii.html) taken from there.